# Finding equivalent formulas

Tags: logic

The question I have on my homework is

"Find a formula that contains no connective other than ¬ and v which is equivalent to ((p→q)→s)."

I drew out the truth table for the given formula but have no idea where to even start to construct an equivalent formula.

$$\begin{array}{c}
p&q&r&\text{((p→q)→s)}\\ \hline
1&1&1&1\\
1&1&0&0\\
1&0&1&1\\
1&0&0&1\\
0&1&1&1\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0
\end{array}$$

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

The game is to replace $\rightarrow$ by $\neg$ and $\lor$ using the conditional law.  Along with DeMorgan's law to swap $\lor$ for $\land$ (and vice versa), you can get expressions using just $\lor$, just $\land$, or just $\rightarrow$, as desired (with $\neg$ always possibly involved).

In case you are not aware of the conditional law, it is that $p \rightarrow q$ is equivalent to $\neg p \lor q$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $p \to q$ is equivalent to $\neg p \vee q$.

Answer (score 0):

We use, twice, the identity $$a\rightarrow b \equiv \lnot a \lor b$$

---

$$\begin{align} (p\rightarrow q) \rightarrow s &\equiv \lnot(p \rightarrow q) \lor s \\ \\
& \equiv \lnot(\lnot p \lor q) \lor s\\ \\
\end{align}$$

---

Remark: Every propositional statement can be expressed in terms of only $\lor$ and $\lnot$.